# Rails Active Model serializers not setting root

Tags: activemodel, active-model-serializers

I have a class that is not an ActiveRecord object and im trying to create a AM serializer for it. I can return the proper json, but its not including a root

in have this in my controller

```
format.json { render json: @current_user, root: "current_user" }
```

and my class looks like this

```
class CurrentUser 
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :user_type, :user_id

end
```

Ive also tried adding this in the controller

```
 def default_serializer_options
  {root: true}
 end
```

But still my json object does not have the root which  I need for Ember Model

return object

```
{"first_name":"Luke","last_name":"Skywalker","user_type":"Padawan","user_id":12}
```

and I need

```
{current_user: {"first_name":"Luke","last_name":"Skywalker","user_type":"Padawan","user_id":12} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `default_serializer_options` inside your controller doesn't work, maybe you should have a look into `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` for `include_root_in_json` option.

If you are curious, concerned source code for that option can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/68598df25ac92038648dccd01b1e4ed534dfc2a2/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb#L13).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone in the future who may come across this same problem,
when using **ActiveModelSerializers 0.10.x**, just add to an existing initializer or create a new one and add this to include the root node in your responses:

*config/initializers/serializer.rb*:

`ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json`

[AMS documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/configuration_options.md) states that this is not backwards compatible for versions 0.9.x and 0.8.x.